# How to give xml string to XDocument in Xpath

Tags: xml, c#-4.0, xpath

I have xml file in string. 
I do not have right to write on disk.
how to pass this string to XPathDocument?

XPathDocument Doc = new XPathDocument(xmlFile);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easier to use XDocument instead of XPathDocument:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to accomplish this by converting the string to a stream, then using the [XPathDocument(Stream) constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xpath.xpathdocument.aspx):

```
string xmlFile;  // TODO get string
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes( xmlFile );
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream( byteArray );
var Doc = new XPathDocument( stream );
```